# Can the AngularJS ui-router state change event for previously visited states before processing be capture?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

ui-router's **stateChangeStart** and **stateChangeSuccess** are perfect for capturing the moment I should display a loader overlay for my web app's UI to present to the user that the transition time is expected and the page has not frozen.

Unfortunately, any state that has previously been viewed and is revisited by the user does not perform as expected. Both events still fire, but it appears that a substantial amount of the processing that occurs during the transition occurs before this event is fired, deeming the loader overlay pretty useless for these cases.

Is there a way to capture the state/route change at an earlier stage in the process so the loader will promptly appear?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that these events are not the proper one. Because lot of processing time *(I'd say)* will be consumed by `$http` loading - not just a state transitioning. I.e. if we are talking about showing progress to user maybe try to check this solution:

- [Angular Loading Bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/)

And if does not fully fit to your needs, take it as inspiration... *(few cites)*

> #### What is this?
>
> There are a few projects like this one, but none that were automatic. They all required you to maintain state on behalf of the progress bar, setting its position manually. This is problematic when you have multiple services all making independent XHR requests. You simply can't have loosly-coupled code in this scenario.
>
> This project is different. It automates the loading bar's progress, by using angular interceptors. Multiple requests within the same time period get bundled together such that each response increments the progress bar by the appropriate amount.